# Django How to pass a checkbox value into a function

Tags: python, django

I have created a table in django, each rows has a id and a checkbox. I have assigned the `value` for each checkbox as the id of the row. When the user clicks on the checkbox I want it to call a function and pass in the `id` number as well as whether that checkbox is now checked.

**sets.html:**

```html
 <td class="text-center">
     {% if set.status %}
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="inputs" value="{{ set.id }}" onclick="location.href='{% url 'dashboard:setUpdate' %}'">
     {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputs" value="{{ set.id }}" onclick="location.href='{% url 'dashboard:setUpdate' %}'">
     {% endif %}
 </td>
```

**views.py**

```py
def set_update(request):
    print(request.GET.getlist('inputs'))
    return redirect('dashboard:sets')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not ajax?:

template.html:

```
<head>
  ...
  <!-- import jquery/ajax -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <!-- create a variable for the csrf token, then load the script.js file -->
  <script> var csrf_token = '{{csrf_token}}' </script> 
  <script src="{% static 'path/to/script.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

script.js:

```
function set_update() {
  
  // submit a request to the backend using ajax:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'the_url',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf_token, // from template.html
      id : $(this).val(),
    },
    success: function(response) set_update_success, // reference to function below:
  });

}

// executed on succesfully receiving a response from the backend:
function set_update_success(response) {

  // unpack response from views.py (below):
  var data = response.data; 
  ...

  // redirect user:
  windlow.location('the_redirect_url');
}

// get all checkboxes and set the click function to 'set_update'
// the identifier can be a class ('.class'), id ('#id'), etc.
$('checkbox-identifier').click(set_update);
```

views.py:

```
def set_update(request):

    # unpack post request:
    the_id = request.POST['id']
    ...

    # execute any logic as needed:
    ...

    # pack response:
    respone = json.dumps({
        'data' : 'some_data',
        ...
    })

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Hello @Daniel, I have never used Ajax before. Also I am using the two values returned as part of a SQL query, which I only know how to do via python.

Comment: No problem, I've elaborated on my answer. If you learn this pattern you can do a lot with django. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected, however I am getting the following issue in console: `Uncaught TypeError: t.nodeName is undefined` which is apparently related to `$(this).val()`